# What is the correct turf for metal studs in rugby?

Tags: equipment, rugby

I have a pair of plastic cleats for practice and dirt fields for play. My question is when would I use metal studded cleats?

Only on rainy and muddy fields, or can/should I use them for also dirt fields that are hard?

I'm under the understanding that the metal studs will make it more difficult to move since they won't grasp the dirt since it's hard and not muddy, hence they won't sink in.

Is this the correct assumption or should they be used if I have them for better grip period?

I should mention I am a forward (open side flanker).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion you should switch for plastic cleats whenever the field is not muddy.

Metal cleats are just a pain on dry fields. It is unconfortable, you can even feel the screws, and feel less stable (when the field is very dry). You wont get much grip compared to plastic cleats.

As an open side flanker, you don't need that much grip in the scrum as you are more stabilizing rather than really pushing. On the other hand, you need speed to detach fast from the scrum, plastic cleats are lighter and thus better for that.